# Helper exist but not exist?

Tags: magento-1.9, helper

Class 'Mage_Amber_Localdev_Helper_Data' not found in /var/www/localdev.site/robert/bsr/app/Mage.php on line 547

is there 100% but won't find it.

```
            $this->addColumn('image', array(
            'header'  => Mage::helper('amber_localdev')->__('Image'),
            'width'   => '80px',
            'nullable'=> true,
            'index'   => 'image',
            'sortable'=> false,
            'renderer' => 'Amber_Localdev_Block_Adminhtml_Image_Grid_Renderer_Thumbnail'
        ));
```

Class rendering image

```
class Amber_Localdev_Block_Adminhtml_Image_Grid_Renderer_Thumbnail extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {

        $val = Mage::helper('eav/entity_attribute_option')->init($row['option_id']);
        $out = "Name";
        $out = "Name".$val;
        $out .= "<img src=". $val ." width='50px'/>";
        return $out;
    }
}
```

My Config:

```
  <global>
<helpers>
  <localdev>
    <class>Amber_Localdev_Helper</class>
  </localdev>
</helpers>
```

...

My Helper: (empty, just a class name)

```
class Amber_Localdev_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{}
```

Comment: are you sure that  `Mage_Amber_Localdev_Helper_Data` is there or `Amber_Localdev_Helper_Data` ?

Comment: Hello Marius, technically in Data.php there is: Amber_Localdev_Helper....

Comment: If I change it to Mage_Amber_Local.... error

Comment: did you clear the cache?

Comment: Cache is off completely :(

Comment: Helpers in config of course declared

Comment: Please add your **config.xml** and **Helper/Data.php**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not seen your config.xml yet, But I am answering as general

```
  $this->addColumn('image', array(
        'header'  => Mage::helper('localdev')->__('Image'),
        'width'   => '80px',
        'nullable'=> true,
        'index'   => 'image',
        'sortable'=> false,
        'renderer' =>   Amber_Localdev_Block_Adminhtml_Image_Grid_Renderer_Thumbnail'
    ));
```

Comment: @RobertA. You are always welcome..